# I can't get OnMouseOver() to notice my mouse hovering over a button in c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmouseover

The script doesn't notice the mouse hovering over a button.  I also want the script to set the game object as active when it sees the mouse and to set the same game object as inactive when it doesn't see the mouse.

here is my code, what is wrong?

```
public class HoverDisplayUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject testPLZWORK;
   
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    
    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        testPLZWORK.SetActive(true);
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        testPLZWORK.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnMouseOver` works on none UI elements with `Collider.isTrigger` check. for UI use `IPointerEnterHandler` instead.